# Javascript innerHTML live console.log the changes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console log every changes i make in google developer tools

```
<div class="test">2</div>
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

So i have a number 2 inside a div, and it prints out 2 in console, but when i edit this div using google developer tools for example to 3, the console log never prints out new changes i make.

Jquery or javascript?

Comment: how it's supposed to know that you made a change ? you need to have an event listener attached to it in order to make it work

Comment: FYI: `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerHTML` is just an awful line of code. Don't use `innerHTML` when you're not getting/setting any actual HTML and [don't use `getElementsByClassName()` at all, much less adding an index to it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is going to re-run your `console.log` line for you unless you tell it to.

In this case, the thing you'd use to tell it to is a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You'd say you want to see all mutations (modifications) to that element's character data, child list, and subtree (most likely).

For example, if you use devtools to change the `foo` in this example, you'll get a notification of that change:

```js
const target = document.querySelector(".test");

const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
});

observer.observe(target, {
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

```html
<div class="test">foo</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for !